# Rails trying to connect to unconfgured MySQL on request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

Seeing a weird problem starting a Unicorn server - `bundle exec ruby unicorn_rails.rb` starts okay, but when I visit a URL, it shows:

```
Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2))
```

So it seems unicorn isn't connecting to the remote server that's configured in database.yml (as it's trying to connect locally), despite other commands, e.g. `bundle exec rails console`, working fine. It seems to be ignoring that setting even though the environment is set right. This was working before, but something has broken it.

I put the full stack trace here:
https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/6029630

database.yml:

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: slide_staging
  host: 192.168.1.255
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  username: deploy
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] || "notconfiguredyet" %>
  timeout: 5000
  reconnect: true
```

Comment: Out of interest have you set the following line in your config/database.yml `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock`?

Comment: @David No, the database is remote, so I don't think any socket is needed.

Comment: Could you paste contents of your `database.yml` file?

Comment: The correct way to launch unicorn is ```bundle exec unicorn rails``` http://unicorn.bogomips.org/ in usage

Comment: What happens when you force the environment with -E flag? `bundle exec unicorn_rails -E 'staging'`

Comment: @yannick tried just now and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It might be linked to the unicorn configuration..

Especially if you preload the app.
Do you have these lines inside?

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is *required* for Rails + "preload_app true",
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this. It turns out the Rails environment was being overridden, as I'd introduced a config snippet that included a bug, using `Rails.env = 'test'` instead of `Rails.env=='test'`. I figured it out after noticing my development mode was running in `test` environment even though `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` was correctly set to `development`.